# Why is my Site not redirecting?

Tags: blogs, blogger, redirect

My [**Site**](http://www.techrone.com) is on the Blogger platform.
I have enabled the redirection option in the settings, still my site is not re-directing to the www.techrone.com

[Screen Shot of Redirection Setting](http://www.techrone.com/p/blog-page_30.html)

Comment: have you pointing your domain correctly? Please update your question with your current domain pointing method.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of A record in your DNS Zone file , remove it and this issue should get resolved

The A Record responsible for this problem is `50.63.202.62`